# iOS launch screen will not stop showing the launchscreen.xib

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, asset-catalog, launchimage

I've made images, an asset file for all the devices I need to support, no errors saying wrong size etc. I have it set up as follows:

[image]

Also I have the asset file set up as follows:

[image]

I've read loads of guides and questions on here regarding this but none of the answers solved my problem. No matter what, it just keeps showing the launchscreen.xib which is set as grey. I've tried rebuilding, cleaning, relaunching the program, everything and it still shows the same grey screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure that there is no "Launch screen interface file base name" key in your Info.plist (the opposite of what Aamir has suggested)
- Delete the app from the device/simulator (in case of simulator I'd suggest also to "Reset Content and Settings")
- Clean the build folder (in Xcode, open "Product" menu, press & hold the alt button, select the "Clean Build Folder..." option)
- Run again

Comment: Works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please add key `Launch screen interface file base name` in `info.plist` and give name of LaunchScreen in its value, hopefully it solves your problem.
For reference I have attached following screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Isn't that for the xib anyway? Otherwise why is it called 'launchscreen'?  I tried it and rebuilt it, relaunched xcode etc but it still doesn't work. I even tried it as 'LaunchImage', the name of my asset but that didn't work either.  Thanks for the quick reply anyway.